# what tool should I use to generate multiple pages pdf file?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, pdf-generation, itext

I'm now working on a .net/c# project requires to generate a contract pdf file (for printing and browsing purpose) based on some info traced from database.

The file also concludes several pages content which is fixed. It seems that crystal report does not deal well with multiple pages files. I also did research online, someone said use iTextSharp.

The question is the format of the file can be complicated. iTextSharp is kinda of not efficient on this issue.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: XML+XSL -> XSL-FO -> PDF is not an option? I would elaborate more, but since I'm working on FO -> PDF engine, it would be kind of ad.

Answer (score 2):

[PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) is an excellent library for this. They also have [Migra-Doc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Overview.ashx) which allows you to write documents to pdf, xps and rtf. The API is robust and based on GDI, pages shouldn't be a problem, you can even draw tables and stuff.

[Quick Samples are here](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/PDFsharpSamples.ashx) but [download the project source](http://www.pdfsharp.net/Downloads.ashx), they have a hoard of good samples.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will check to see if it is a solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/) (I'm the CTO at Windward). With Windward you design in Word, Excel, or PowerPoint so anything, no matter how complex, that you can layout in Office, we can then render with data in PDF.